Proof related to Markov chains
I am working on a homework assignment, and the question is as follows:
Given the Markov property:
$P[X_{t+1}|X_0,X_1, \dots ,X_t] = P[X_{t+1}|X_t]$
Prove:
$P[X_{t+1},X_{t+2}, \dots ,X_{t+m}|X_0,X_1, \dots ,X_t] = P[X_{t+1},X_{t+2}, \dots ,X_{t+m}|X_t]$
I have tried proving it left to right, right to left, and by induction, but I noticed I am always stuck at proving something like this (a specific case):
$P[X_3|X_2, X_1] = P[X_3|X_2]$
I understand the intuitive meaning behind this, but haven't been able to mathematically prove it given only the above Markov property.
Any help is appreciated!

To prove the specific equality you are asking for (and all the others like it), you use conditioning. This is part of a more general story of so-called conditional expectations.
We show that $\mathbb P(X_3|X_2,X_1)=\mathbb P(X_3|X_2)$.
We have
$$
\mathbb P(X_3=a_3|X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1)=\frac{\sum_{a_0}\mathbb P(X_3=a_3,X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1,X_0=a_0)}
{\sum_{a_0}\mathbb P(X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1,X_0=a_0)}.
$$
$$
=\frac{\sum_{a_0}\mathbb P(X_3=a_3|X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1,X_0=a_0)\mathbb P(X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1,X_0=a_0)}{\sum_{a_0}\mathbb P(X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1,X_0=a_0)}
$$
$$
=\frac{\sum_{a_0}\mathbb P(X_3=a_3|X_2=a_2)\mathbb P(X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1,X_0=a_0)}{\sum_{a_0}\mathbb P(X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1,X_0=a_0)}
$$
$$
=\mathbb P(X_3=a_3|X_2=a_2)\frac{\sum_{a_0}\mathbb P(X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1,X_0=a_0)}{\sum_{a_0}\mathbb P(X_2=a_2,X_1=a_1,X_0=a_0)}
$$
$$=\mathbb P(X_3=a_3|X_2=a_2).
$$

Perfect! Bringing in all variables before $t$ using the summation was the key and I missed it. Thanks!

Hi: The specific case you refer to is the Markov property which is given. The Markov property says that $P(X_{t+1} | X_t $ along with anything else in the sigma algebra defined by the filtration $) ~= P(X_{t+1} | X_{t})$. So, your definition of the Markov property is fine but it holds for any number of past $X_{i}$ except for the most recent, namely $X_{t}$.

Yup, I understood the intuition but never quite proved it. The answer above proves this.

yes, antonyquas constructed a nice proof. But still,it's useful to keep in mind that one doesn't need to condition all the way back to $X_{0}$ in order for the markov property to hold. If it holds, it holds for any number of past $X_{i}$.

Yup, this will be helpful to simply plug and use later on.
